# How can I check the Fire OS version programmatically?

Tags: android, amazon-fire-tv

I'd like to check programmatically the Fire OS version of my running device. **Not the Android version**.

The reason I want that version is because there is one capability which is not shown on old Fire OS versions and I'd like to include it on my app.

Note: sometimes the devices are not updating the OS immediately.

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to access the FireOS version. Which capability are you trying to use? Is it possible to do feature detection instead?

Comment: The feature is available because Android +5.0 supports this, but is not present in older FireOS (settings). The feature is 'Modifying subtitles' (text color, background,..). So, when is not present I'd like to show that feature in the app, otherwise hide it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In one of my FireTV apps I needed to track that, so I use:

```
Log.v(TAG,Build.MANUFACTURER + " " + Build.MODEL + " " + Build.DEVICE+ " " + Build.VERSION.INCREMENTAL + " " + Build.SERIAL);
```

to get fairly specific version and device model info. I've not updated the app for a while so not 100% sure it's still going to give you what you need (won't be near a device I can check with for a few days)

Comment: Thanks for the answer: it doesn't show the Fire OS Version

Comment: while it doesn't give a 'friendly' version (eg 5.2.4.0) it does give the current OS version 36.5.6.5_user_565189620 which you can (if you need) decode from http://www.aftvnews.com/amazon-fire-tv-fire-tv-stick-software-update-history/

Answer (score 1):

There's not an easy or consistent way to detect the Fire OS version programmatically. However, for the feature you want to detect, try getting an instance of `CaptioningManager` and call [`getUserStyle()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/CaptioningManager.html#getUserStyle()). On older versions of Fire TV, this method used to return `null`, but now I believe an actual value gets returned. I haven't tested this, though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's not null on the versions which has this capability, but it's not shown on the settings.